# How to differentiate stack/heap addresses in llvm IR code?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'd like to find a way to determine if a load/store operand in LLVM IR is a stack address or a heap address in an LLVM pass (the pass coded in C++), i.e.

```
if (inst is a store) {
  if (inst->getOperand(1) is a heap address) {
    // do something with the heap address
  }
}
```

And operate similarly for loads. Looking in the IR code, they are referenced the same:

```
store i32 5, i32* %c, align 4 // storing value to a local variable
store i32 1, i32* %4, align 4 // storing value to something on the heap, do something with the heap address
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My frontend does this (well, something a little like it). You may not be able to do it well enough to reach your goals, but if you do, this is one approach:

Regard each return result of `malloc()` (or whatever your allocator is called) as a heap variable and each result of `alloca()` as a stack variable. For each of those, classify more values by looking at `for(auto x : y->users())`; a getelementptr or cast of a `malloc()` is also a heap variable.

However, this doesn't classify every value. Loading a pointer from a struct/array on the heap may return something on the stack and vice versa. Function arguments may be either. But perhaps you don't need to classify *every* value.